# Android studio getting error IOException: Operation not permitted while creating file

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions

I am trying to create a file. (testipfs folder already exists)

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "testipfs");
File photo= new File(imagesFolder, "desktopWallpaper.jpg");
System.out.println("Saving file in "+photo.getAbsolutePath());
if (!photo.exists()) {
   try {
      photo.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Failed to create photo");
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

But getting error Operation not permitted.

```
I/System.out: Saving file in /storage/emulated/0/testipfs/desktopWallpaper.jpg
I/System.out: Failed to create photo
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at com.example.ipfs.MainActivity.SavePhotoTask(MainActivity.java:49)
        at com.example.ipfs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)
```

I have added permission in my manifest file as bellow

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

How do i solve this problem?

Comment: Firstly if you didn't check the permission in runtime use this:
`public boolean isExternalStorageWritable(){    
String state= Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}`
It might be about permissions or maybe that file is created and you overwrite it.

Comment: @AhmetKorkmaz this method returns true. So i do have permission. The file does not exists, i am not overwriting it, i am trying to create. Even if so why i can not overwrite it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am expecting you are testing your application in android 11, In Android 11 things changed ... You have to ask for this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and in you MainActivity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30){
        if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
            Intent getpermission = new Intent();
            getpermission.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(getpermission);
        }
    }
```

Basically this is just an intent which will take user to setting to give us Permission, and this is necessary in android 11 , If you just asking for READ nd WRITE permission then you application is having just a read-only access to files in the device

Comment: I wonder why this don't have upvote. This worked for me.

Comment: Google has restrictions on this and your app should fall on the allowed use case to have this, https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access-google-play

Comment: Man/Woman you saved me :)

Answer (score 6):

Try to add `requestLegacyExternalStorage` in Manifest.xml file, if you are using Android 10 or later versions.

```
<application
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

Comment: Thanks @kirill-karmazin for your valuable response

Comment: After trying every other manifest change above, this one finally got me past throw of exception. So, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had special characters in my directory name (specifically ":").  Removing this allowed me to save the file

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
     Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "testipfs");

File photo = new File(imagesFolder, "desktopWallpaper.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring permissions in the Manifest file is not enough if you are using Android Marshmallow and above, before you write or read any external files you need to request the appropriate permissions explicitly.

[storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

- If this doesn't work try setting your `targetSdkVersion` to 28 or less.