# Why android can't open sqlite db from external storage on android 30 upwards

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm updating the target sdk version on an android app and in the process, I picked up the sqlite db importer is broken. Previously on android version >= 29, the importer worked fine.

So Basically, the android app has its own internal sqlite, During the import process, it opens an external db and imports the data into its internal database. The app uses the code below to open the db from sqliteHelper in Section A. To select and set the db name and path, the app uses the android file-selector "startActivityForResult" with an intent. Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated. **I'm setting this permission in manifest and during runtime: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

Section A
`SQLiteDatabase db = ImportDBHelper.getInstance(context).getReadableDatabase();`

````
public class ImportDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DATABASE_NAME = "None";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;
    private static ImportDBHelper instance;

    private ImportDBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                
    }

    public static synchronized ImportDBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ImportDBHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}```
````

2022-07-02 16:04:27.483 17932-18316/app.example E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 40888 of [bcd014c473]
2022-07-02 16:04:27.483 17932-18316/app.example E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:40888: (13) open(/storage/emulated/0/Download/B3.sqlite) -
2022-07-02 16:04:27.483 17932-18316/app.example E/SQLiteLog: (1) Process m.genioroasters : Pid (17932) Uid (10286) Euid (10286) Gid (10286) Egid (10286)
2022-07-02 16:04:27.483 17932-18316/app.example E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /storage/emulated/0/Download/B3.sqlite : st_mode (100660) st_uid (0) st_gid (9997) st_ino(15987) st_size(110592)
2022-07-02 16:04:27.483 17932-18316/app.example E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /storage/emulated/0/Download : st_mode(40770) st_uid(0) st_gid(9997) st_ino(6634)
2022-07-02 16:04:27.483 17932-18316/app.example E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /storage/emulated/0 : st_mode(40770) st_uid(0) st_gid(9997) st_ino(4856)
2022-07-02 16:04:27.483 17932-18316/app.example E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /storage/emulated : st_mode(40711) st_uid(0) st_gid(9997) st_ino(238)
2022-07-02 16:04:27.483 17932-18316/app.example E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /storage : st_mode(40711) st_uid(2000) st_gid(9997) st_ino(13855)

2022-07-02 16:04:27.490 17932-18316/app.example E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/storage/emulated/0/Download/B3.sqlite'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/storage/emulated/0/Download/B3.sqlite': File /storage/emulated/0/Download/B3.sqlite is not readable
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:371)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:226)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:736)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:284)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:251)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1415)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:997)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:480)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:437)
at app.example.adapters.DatabaseAdapter.importDatabase(DatabaseAdapter.java:578)
at app.example.Views.ParentActivity$1DBimporter.doInBackground(ParentActivity.java:260)
at app.example.Views.ParentActivity$1DBimporter.doInBackground(ParentActivity.java:247)
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 2318 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EACCES[2318]): Could not open database

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Download/B3.sqlite` -- you do not have filesystem access to files in `Download/` that your app did not put there.

Comment: Ah. greaaaat. Thank you very much @CommonsWare . So I used this solution to give the app permissions to manage all files on the device: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68984041/6632458

Comment: Well... I suggest using these database on android. See [clorabase databases](https://databases.clorabase.tk)